# Change Multiple Line Stroke in Illustrator and mantain the same distance between them

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I have a serious problem. I want to change the weight of multiple lines but when I try do that the distance between them disapears and overlap. In straight lines that doesn´t happens, but in diagonal lines this happens always!!! Please can annyone help me please??!!!

[image: Before change stroke]

[image: After change stroke]

Thank You

Comment: This seems like a metro-map to me :) and I _think_ this might just be a question of grouping and scaling.

Comment: This might help: http://www.cambooth.net/archives/837

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a set of lines go from horizontal to a diagonal, all your points are stacked along the same vertical:

[image: lines demonstration]

In order to maintain the same thickness and spacing for a diagonal line, your points must line up on an angle that is relational to the magnitude of the angle of the change in direction:

[image: lines demonstration 2]

Comment: A good way to achieve the neat line-up is using a closed shape and using `Object > Path > Offset Path...`.

Comment: Agreed offset is the way to go. You can get the angle by expanding the stroke and see where the vertices are,

Answer (score 1):

Most objects in Illustrator are unaware of their surrounding objects. There is no way to automatically move any object based on the stroke size of any surrounding object.

You're best bet is to manually adjust any overlapping you do not want or to select all and use the `Scale Tool` or `Object > Transform > Scale` menu item, ensuring `Scale Strokes & Effects` is **checked** on the `Transform Panel`. If you scale the strokes rather than increasing their weights manually you'll get thicker strokes and the distance between the strokes will also scale simultaneously. It is simply more difficult to target a specific stroke weight when using the scale method.